# How to find the sum of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1} \frac{3^n}{n5^n}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

In particular, it's the $\frac{1}{n}$ term that throws me off; without it, it's a simple geometric series, but I was under the impression that, *broadly speaking,* the only infinite sums whose value we could calculate were either geometric or telescoping. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Hint: Define $g(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}x^{n-1}$, try to sum this series and calculate $\int g(x) dx$. Then evaluate it at an appropriate value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integrating the series $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{n\geqslant0}x^n=\frac1{1-x}$, one gets $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{n\geqslant1}\frac{x^n}n=-\log(1-x)$ for every $|x|\lt1$. Use this for a specific value of $x$...

> ...namely, $x=-\dfrac35$.

Comment: Sir how do you hide the text?

Comment: Did & @Winther thank you for the incredibly fast response. Is it safe to say that the ability to solve this (for an average undergrad) comes purely from exposure? This is the first time I've encountered such a question and I just don't see how one would make such a connection without some prompting. (For context, I teach, and generally like to help students understand general strategies for solving questions, but I don't see what I could offer them here: while simple enough, it's rather insightful... Anyhow, thank you!